# How to find missing records in column B Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have two columns in my excel sheet (column A,column B) and  contains some same records and i need  to find missing records in column B.

Example

```
ColumnA           ColumnB     ColumnC
1A                   1A         
2B                              2B
3C                              3C
4D                   4D
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52278967/edit) your question

Comment: @Rahul: put this in column C `=IF(B2="",A2,"")`

Comment: I tried  that Srijan and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to mind right away:

- Sort by Column B
- Apply a filter to the spreadsheet, and filter the
  values in column B that are blank.

Comment: Thanks El Guapo,it is not working as expected ,is there any formula to get missing records in column c

Comment: I misunderstood your goal.  It seems like @Srijan's comment was exactly what you are looking for.  In cell C2, use the formula =IF(B2="",A2,"") and then apply that formula to the rest of the column by dragging the bottom corner of the cell down to the rest of the cells in column C that have have a value in column A.  Or copy cell C2, then select the cells in column C (for example C3 through C10) and paste.  The formula will be applied to each of the cells in column C, but each formula will correspond to the row that it is in.  Cell C3's formula will be =IF(B3="",A3,"") and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

In C2, try to enter the following formula:

```
=IF(OR($B2="",COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)>0),"",$A2)
```

Then drag it down. This assumes that records in columns A and B aren't exactly aligned with each other (ex. A2 has a value of "x" while B100000 has the same value - they're not within the same row, but the "x" record indeed exists somewhere in column B).